# How to use Campaign's Name in an Email sent with 'Send List Email' feature?

Tags: email, email-template, campaign, campaign-member, summer-18

I'm composing an email to be sent to all members of my campaign. I use Summer '18 Release's new feature which is mass email sending through the campaign object.

What I need is putting Campaign's Name in the message but I'm unable to find a way to do it. I tried:

`{!Campaign.Name}`, `{{Campaign.Name}}`, `{{{Campaign.Name}}}`

But none of these worked.

In the message window there's an option to insert Merge Fields:

[image]

But there are only 3 types which I can use:

[image]

Does it mean it's impossible to use Campaign's Name?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use Campaign merge fields in list emails.  At least, not yet.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_list_email_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: Can you include a relevant snippet or citation from the linked documentation so this answer can stand alone and users do not have to navigate away?